# SitecoreService.GetItem not returning Children/Child Items

Tags: glass-mapper

The below code is not returning the children's,

```
var TemplateID = Guid.Parse("{51A26CD4-FCB5-4A3C-8720-2D60F625A678}");           
var _Options = new GetItemByIdOptions(TemplateID)
{
    InferType = true,
    Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Enabled
};
var target = context.SitecoreService.GetItem<IGlassModel>(_Options);
```

Below is the Model :

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{19CDADF8-D474-42C9-8C8D-522A7FF93663}", AutoMap=true)]
    public class IGlassModel
    {
        Guid Id { get; set; }

        string Path { get; set; }

        //[SitecoreItem]
        //string Name { get; set; }

        [SitecoreChildren]
        IEnumerable<Country> Chlidren { get; set; }

    }       

    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{780F8593-3AFA-4DF0-98EE-16FFDD18F88F}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class Country
    {
        Guid Id { get; set; }

        string Path { get; set; }

        [SitecoreItem]
        string CountryName { get; set; }

        [SitecoreItem]
        string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you please share also the `IGlassModel`?

Comment: @TamásTárnok, Updated with IGlassModel.

Comment: Try adding `virtual` modifier for `Children`

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue any adding `virtual` keyword worked for us as @Marek is saying in comments as well.

```
[SitecoreChildren]
public virtual IEnumerable<Country> Chlidren { get; set; }
```

> Glass mapper document states - One important thing to remember when
> writing class with Glass.Mapper is to ensure that all your fields are
> marked as virtual. Glass.Mapper can automatically infer what data to
> load for your model by using a combination of On Demand mapping and
> Auto-Mapping.

You can refer blog that is explaining why all Glass mapper field should be virtual -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105212/why-should-all-glass-mapper-fields-be-virtual

Comment: Added virtual keyword. but now i'm getting this error "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IGlassModelProxy' does not exist in the namespace 'Castle.Proxies' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"